# SQL Merge Similar Rows and Concat Certain Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which looks like:

```
ID-----Name-----Version
1 | TestX | 1.2
2 | TestX | 1.2
3 | TestX | 1.2
4 | TestX | 1.3
5 | TestX | 1.3
```

I need to query it based on Name and Version and have the results look like:

```
ID-----Name-----Version
1,2,3 | TestX | 1.2
4,5   | TestX | 1.3
```

I cannot figure out how to get the concat to work as I want.

Comment: Search for [sql server group_concat](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+group_concat&rlz=1C1GGRV_enNL796NL796&oq=sql+server+group&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.4447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @HoneyBadger group_concat - awesome learn something new everyday! I think this is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR XML PATH()` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF(tt.id, 1, 1, '') AS ID, t.Name, t.Version
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ', ' + t1.id
      FROM table t1 
      WHERE t1.Name = t.Name AND t1.version = t.Version 
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ) tt(id);
```

If you are working the latest version of `SQL Server` then you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(ID, ', ') as ID, Name, Version
FROM table t
GROUP BU Name, Version;
```

Comment: I will give your first solution a try and report back. 

I wish I was using the latest version - string_agg() would make this whole thing so much easier (and was the first solution my searching gave me).